# How to get the current time during the simulation

Tags: anylogic

I would like to display the current time during my simulation so that I can simulate with full screen and also have the time. I tried the function getMinute(Date date) and a variable date. I didn't get an error but I also didn't get the time. Is it also possible to have a clock which displays the time?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
String.format("%02d:%02d",getHourOfDay(), getMinute())
```

This will give you a string with the current time during the simulation

You can also use the clock object in the pictures palette to display time

you can use `date()` to know the date and time

Comment: @JackSock, can I recommend you get used to using the AnyLogic help first? Lots of stuff there, see here for example: https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Ffunctions%2FTime_functions.html&resultof=%22%63%75%72%72%65%6e%74%22%20%22%74%69%6d%65%22%20